# LNA and DC amplification

Tags: preamp, detector, matching, lna

In a THz detector, it produces a DC output voltage proportional to the input signal intensity. I need high SNR.

My doubts are:

- Can I use LNA as a preamplifier?
- Is DC amplification possible with LNA?
- Is matching always required between

  1. Antenna and detector,
  2. Detector and LNA?

Comment: What is an LNA?

Comment: @tobalt Low-Noise Amplifier. A term from the world of RF. Which is a bit strange - prashanth says the detector outputs DC.

Answer (score 2):

> *In a THz detector, it produces a DC output voltage proportional to the
> input signal intensity. I need high SNR.*

Let's just be clear about things. If you wish to amplify a DC or slow moving signal, you would use an amplifier that is suitable for DC and, you would pay particular attention to filtering to give you the lowest noise possible. If the signal intensity changes fairly slowly (maybe it has a bandwidth of 100 Hz and you have to decide that) then, there's absolutely no point using an amplifier that has a bandwidth of much more than 100 Hz.

So, when you say "LNA" and are talking about radio receivers, what first springs to mind are the types of LNA produced by such companies as [Mini-Circuits](https://www.minicircuits.com/). When they offer an "LNA" for sale it's for RF amplification and, that would be totally inappropriate for use as an accurate and low-noise DC amplifier.

You would use an op-amp for DC amplification or, an InAmp and, there are plenty to choose from.

> *Is matching always required between Antenna and detector, Detector and
> LNA?*

An antenna needs to be matched to the circuit it feeds. The output of a detector is baseband and doesn't generally need matching on its output but, the devil will be in the details and you have provided nothing in that respect hence, all I can do is generalize.

Comment: But why do they use LNA in RF power detector (its output is also DC)

Comment: @prashanth LNA stands for low noise amplifier (as I'm sure you know) and, can mean absolutely anything. In the context of RF carrier or IF signal processing it will not be used to amplify DC. If you have an example of a detector that uses an LNA please provide a link to it so I can properly assess what they might mean. But, remember that your question above is about signal intensity and not detection (two different things).

Comment: Actually, my goal is to detect THz signals using graphene. The phenomenon of detection is: Constant DC voltage (proportional to THz signal level) is developed between drain and source when a THz signal is applied with suitable bias at the gate source of Graphene FET. But the DC outptut is very small. So, I need a output stage to amplify with less noise.

Comment: If I just use an InAmp at DC, 1/f noise dominates.

Comment: What are you expecting me to tell you @prashanth

Comment: like what can be used for the output stage with less noise at the output?

Comment: Engineering is about numbers. Please state the expected DC levels and how fast might those DC levels need change in time. But, you need to explain what the output connects to and what the input impedance of the amplifier needs to be. The expected gain of the amplifier is also needed. Also @prashanth take note that your original questions have been answered.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use LNA as a preamplifier?

You use the least-noise amplifier you can afford and that has the required properties. So, yes. That's typically what LNAs are used for: the first stage of amplification. See *Friis' Noise Formula*.

> Is DC amplification possible with LNA?

That fully depends on your LNA.

> Is matching always required between

Short answer: no, it's not *always* required. You do it for a particular reason, and that is to maximize power transfer and to avoid reflections, in this case.

> 1. Antenna and detector,

However, I'm excited to see how you build a matched transmission line for the THz radiation! Are you sure you're conducting THz, and not some mixed-down signal?

> Detector and LNA?

That would sound good.

Comment: I am designing a THz detector that produces constant DC output voltage using graphene transistors. Thinking of using a differential patch antenna which creates virtual ground and elimates DC coupling capacitors for detector. Antenna output is directly connected to the gate of transistor.

Comment: but a DC output doesn't need an LNA or impedance matching. Are you sure it's actually DC?

Comment: Yeah it's DC with very small magnitude